# Select data from table

Tags: mysql, select

I have table name chat as below

[image]

I am trying with below query I can get data

```
SELECT chat_detail_id,from_user_id,to_user_id,time FROM chat as c WHERE c.to_user_id='3' OR c.from_user_id='3'
```

But If I fetch data with user id = 3 (c.to_user_id='3' OR c.from_user_id='3') I want a one column name with other_id have value of from_user_id OR to_user_id other than fetch user id in my case is 3

Output as below highlighted in red this s other_id row:

[image]

Any help would be great appreciated

Comment: Do you mean that other_id is the other guy talking with ID 3?

Comment: Yes exactly It is either from_user_id or to_user_id

Comment: On what code are you doing this? PHP?

Comment: Please post your schema and sample data instead of screen shots. How is anyone to try this out with only screen shots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two approaches to solve this issue.

You can solve it using PHP or by using SQL.

If you chose to use PHP,

You do the same query and then make an if statement after your fetch.

```
if($fetched['to_user_id'] == '3')
    $other_id = $fetched['from_user_id'];
else
    $other_id = $fetched['to_user_id'];
```

The other option is to do it with your SQL query.

```
SELECT chat_detail_id,from_user_id,to_user_id,CASE c.to_user_id WHEN '3' THEN (c.from_user_id) ELSE (c.to_user_id) END AS other_id FROM chat as c WHERE (c.to_user_id='3' OR c.from_user_id='3')
```

EDIT: Fixed, works now.